# How do I get lat/long in a custom tiled google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I created a custom Google map with my own tiles, and I am trying to find the latitude and longitude of points to place markers. I am using Google Maps API v3.

Following the "Event Context V3", I can get the lat/long of the centered position using this script:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    alert(center.toString());
  });
```

How can I do this by just clicking on a part of the map, rather than dragging the map and changing the center?

Comment: I recall seeing an option in the Labs extensions of Google Maps that added a Lat/Long tooltip to the mouse.. would that help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            alert(event.latLng);
        });
```

?

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot, Aniri. It was so simple... haha